# cannot rebase: you have unstaged changes git

Tags: git

I am on a branch named new_nlp and when I do a git status, I get the following:

```
# On branch new_nlp
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    untitled.
```

I cannot see this file untitled as it is deleted.

I want to switch to master and perform a rebase from new_nlp but when I checkout master and issue the command:

```
git rebase new_nlp
```

I get the following error message:

```
cannot rebase: you have unstaged changes
D   untitled.
```

I cannot see this file and I have no idea how to delete it.  I have no idea how it got added.

Does anyone know how I can get past this road block.  I have no idea why the file remains in the index.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the file is deleted and is already tracked by git. you can:

1. delete the file and commit the change (`git rm --cached untitled; git commit`) or
2. run `git checkout -- untitled` to get back the file

Comment: Awesome.  I was struggling with this for like 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove it from the index using `git rm untitled.`

Comment: git will most likely complain. either use `--cached` or `-f` options